# In tcp, one receive buffer for each connection? Or all the connections share one buffer?

Tags: tcp, buffer

For example, in the server endpoint, if I set the receive buffer size to 1k, and there are 100 connections, are these 100 connections share this 1k receive buffer? Or each connection has its own 1k receive buffer?
And is it same for send buffer?

Answer (score 4):

> For example, in the server endpoint, if I set the receive buffer size 1k, and there is 100 connections. Is these 100 connections share this 1k receive buffer?

No.

> Or each connection has their own 1k receive buffer?

See below.

> And is it same for send buffer?

Yes.

Every *socket* has its own send and receive buffer. That's why you have to specify the socket when setting or getting them.